# Custom field deleted from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I am using custom fields in wordpress. but recently my 1 custom field is deleted from the website. Here is post example 
http://moviegore.com/siberian-education-educazione-siberiana-2013/
Deleted custom field: Year
which file should I check?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't just delete custom fields, what did you change last?

Comment: I had hired someone to fix post rating plugin he is disappeared and after that "Year" custom field was also deleted.

Comment: However its not deleted from older posts, But i am not able to add it in new posts.

Comment: Maybe you can check the [screen options](https://en.support.wordpress.com/screen-options/). It could be unchecked?

Comment: only one custom field is missing from drop down menu. check the screenshot http://moviegore.com/custom-fields.jpg

Comment: Ok, then I would disable the plugin, check if it causes the problem. If not, check the place where you register the custom field. Fact that current posts already have this setting is because Wordpress doesn't delete these values when the custom field is removed.